# Data Table header not aligned in bootstrap tab

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, datatable

I am trying to use DataTable with Twitter bootstrap Tabs and for that i am trying following code, Its calling dataTable successfully  and creating dataTable but for tab2 DataTable header got mis-aligned

```
 <div>
    <!-- Nav tabs -->
    <ul class="nav nav-tabs" role="tablist">
        <li role="presentation" class="active"><a href="#home" aria-controls="home" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">Data table 1</a>

        </li>
        <li role="presentation"><a href="#profile" aria-controls="profile" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">Data table 2</a>

    </ul>
    <!-- Tab panes -->
    <div class="tab-content">
        <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane active" id="home">
            <table class="table" id="table1">
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th>#</th>
                        <th>First table</th>
                        <th>First table</th>
                        <th>First table</th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                    <tr>
                        <th scope="row">1</th>
                        <td>Mark</td>
                        <td>Otto</td>
                        <td>@mdo</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <th scope="row">2</th>
                        <td>Jacob</td>
                        <td>Thornton</td>
                        <td>@fat</td>
                    </tr>

                </tbody>
            </table>
        </div>
        <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane" id="profile">
            <table class="table" id="table2">
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th>#</th>
                        <th>second table</th>
                        <th>second table</th>
                        <th>second table</th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                    <tr>
                        <th scope="row">1</th>
                        <td>Mark</td>
                        <td>Otto</td>
                        <td>@mdo</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <th scope="row">2</th>
                        <td>Jacob</td>
                        <td>Thornton</td>
                        <td>@fat</td>
                    </tr>

                </tbody>
            </table>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

When i add `scrollY` header gets un-aligned

[image: jsFiddle]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Its because your second tab is hidden when you initialize and scroll the table2. Here is working example. [jsFiddleDemo](https://jsfiddle.net/sLrnzwz1/4/)

```
$("#table1").DataTable({
    "scrollY": 308,
    "paging": false,
    "responsive": true
});
$('a[href="#profile"]').one('click',function(){
    setTimeout(function(){
        $("#table2").DataTable({
            "scrollY": 308,
            "paging": false,
            "responsive": true
        });
    },0);
});
```

Comment: Thanks its working fine, though i have that idea, but still do have any idea why this is happening ?

Comment: Mostly because table2 is hidden in another tab and might not get the height due to its hidden and can not set the position of scrollY. Though this is my assumptions and I might be wrong, but this is my initial thought.